# Copy textbox value and enclose copied value to single quotations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two textbox that are mirrored with each other. Whenever the user inputs into textbox 1 will automatically be copied to textbox 2. But is it possible to have it copied to textbox 2 and have single quotations and upon putting a comma, another value will be closed with single quotations.

For example:
User input (textbox1): apple

textbox 2 (copied value): 'apple'

User input (textbox1): apple, orange

textbox 2 (copied value): 'apple','orange'

Im not even sure if it's possible but every help will be appreciated. So far, this is what I have for copying the values of the textboxes

```js
function sync()
 {
   var n1 = document.getElementById('sample1');
   var n2 = document.getElementById('sample2');
   n2.value = n1.value;
 }
```

```html
 Input 1: <input type="text" style= "width: 230px; padding-left: 3px" id="sample1" name="sample1" onkeyup="sync()"> 

<br>
 Copied Input: <input type="text" style= "width: 230px; padding-left: 3px" id="sample2" name="sample2">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the variable with your input using a function as:

```js
function sync()
{
var result= '\'' + $('#sample1').val().split(',').join('\',\'') + '\'';
$('#sample2').val(result)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="sample1" onkeyup="sync()">
<input type="text" id="sample2">
```

Answer (score 0):

**See below example**

```js
function sync()
 {
   var n1 = document.getElementById('sample1');
   var n2 = document.getElementById('sample2');

     var newval = "'" + n1.value.split( "," ).join( "','" ) + "'";
   n2.value = newval;
 }
```

```html
 Input 1: <input type="text" style= "width: 230px; padding-left: 3px" id="sample1" name="sample1" onkeyup="sync()"> 

<br>
 Copied Input: <input type="text" style= "width: 230px; padding-left: 3px" id="sample2" name="sample2">
```